# My model gets distorted when I rig it

Tags: modeling

I made  wolf model:

[image]

I started to follow tutorials to rig the head to prepare my wolf to animation. And when I wanted to see the result in object mode, this :

[image]

I unwraped my model, I remove the X-mirror options and some modifiers, nothing.
Could you help me to fix this ?

Btw : I'm not a native english speaker, so my english is quite bad, if you don't understand something, I can try to say it differently

Have a nice day

Comment: Probably, first thing to try: apply scale. In object mode Ctrl A then choose scale. If it does not work, please upload the blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me, but finally I fixed my problem (I forgot to delete a shape key, oops ^^)

Comment: @Lymphaa you can add that as an answer. (someone else might have this problem too.) PS your English is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to inspect for keyframes that you didn't mean to place but accidentally did. I have had a similar result especially when using cntl+option+0 to place a camers